# Как получить несколько серийных номеров?

Tags: java, applet, hdd

Получаю самый первый серийный номер из трёх, а как получить все три?

```
private ThreadUtils() {  }
public static String getHdd() {
String result = "";
  try {
    File file = File.createTempFile("realhowto",".vbs");
    file.deleteOnExit();
    FileWriter fw = new java.io.FileWriter(file);

    String vbs =
      "Set objWMIService = GetObject(\"winmgmts:\\\\.\\root\\cimv2\")\n"
      + "Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery _ \n"
      + "   (\"Select * from win32_DISKDRIVE\") \n"
      + "For Each objItem in colItems \n"
      + "    Wscript.Echo objItem.SerialNumber \n"
      + "    exit for  ' do the first cpu only! \n"
      + "Next \n";

    fw.write(vbs);
    fw.close();
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cscript //NoLogo " + file.getPath());
    BufferedReader input =
      new BufferedReader
        (new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
       result += line;
    }
    input.close();
  }
  catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return result.trim();
}

public static String hdds = getHdd();
```

Получаю в переменную первый из трех серийников:

```
public static String hdds = getHdd();
```

Answer (score 1):

В вашем запросе:

```
String vbs =
  "Set objWMIService = GetObject(\"winmgmts:\\\\.\\root\\cimv2\")\n"
  + "Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery _ \n"
  + "   (\"Select * from win32_DISKDRIVE\") \n"
  + "For Each objItem in colItems \n"
  + "    Wscript.Echo objItem.SerialNumber \n"
  + "    exit for  ' do the first cpu only! \n"
  + "Next \n";
```

явно стоит (наверное копипаст) `+ "    exit for  ' do the first cpu only! \n"` уберите эту строку и должно заработать.

Comment: Да, копипаст, именно. Спасибо за подсказку, помогло...